# Select most reviewed courses starting from courses having at least 2 reviews

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy with PostgreSQL. I have the following two models:

```
class Course(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True )
    course_name =db.Column(db.String(120))
    course_description = db.Column(db.Text)
    course_reviews = db.relationship('Review', backref ='course', lazy ='dynamic')

class Review(db.Model):
    __table_args__ = ( db.UniqueConstraint('course_id', 'user_id'), { } )
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True )
    review_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)#default=db.func.now()
    review_comment = db.Column(db.Text)
    rating = db.Column(db.SmallInteger)
    course_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('course.id') )
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id') )
```

I want to select the courses that are most reviewed starting with at least two reviews. The following SQLAlchemy query worked fine with SQlite:

```
most_rated_courses = db.session.query(models.Review, func.count(models.Review.course_id)).group_by(models.Review.course_id).\
          having(func.count(models.Review.course_id) >1) \   .order_by(func.count(models.Review.course_id).desc()).all()
```

But when I switched to PostgreSQL in production it gives me the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column "review.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT review.id AS review_id, review.review_date AS review_...
               ^
 'SELECT review.id AS review_id, review.review_date AS review_review_date, review.review_comment AS review_review_comment, review.rating AS review_rating, review.course_id AS review_course_id, review.user_id AS review_user_id, count(review.course_id) AS count_1 \nFROM review GROUP BY review.course_id \nHAVING count(review.course_id) > %(count_2)s ORDER BY count(review.course_id) DESC' {'count_2': 1}
```

I tried to fix the query by adding models.Review in the GROUP BY clause but it did not work:

```
most_rated_courses = db.session.query(models.Review, func.count(models.Review.course_id)).group_by(models.Review.course_id).\
          having(func.count(models.Review.course_id) >1) \.order_by(func.count(models.Review.course_id).desc()).all()
```

Can anyone please help me with this issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have all three of these: both the parent.id and the parent.childForeignKeyId, and finally the Child.id?

Comment: @RetroCoder sorry, I don't get your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLite and MySQL both have the behavior that they allow a query that has aggregates (like count()) without applying GROUP BY to all other columns - which in terms of standard SQL is invalid, because if more than one row is present in that aggregated group, it has to pick the first one it sees for return, which is essentially random.

So your query for Review basically returns to you the first "Review" row for each distinct course id - like for course id 3, if you had seven "Review" rows, it's just choosing an essentially random "Review" row within the group of "course_id=3".   I gather the answer you really want, "Course", is available here because you can take that semi-randomly selected Review object and just call ".course" on it, giving you the correct Course, but this is a backwards way to go.

But once you get on a proper database like Postgresql you need to use correct SQL.   The data you need from the "review" table is just the course_id and the count, nothing else, so query just for that (first assume we don't actually need to display the counts, that's in a minute):

```
most_rated_course_ids = session.query(
                        Review.course_id,
                    ).\
                    group_by(Review.course_id).\
                    having(func.count(Review.course_id) > 1).\
                    order_by(func.count(Review.course_id).desc()).\
                    all()
```

but that's not your Course object - you want to take that list of ids and apply it to the course table.  We first need to keep our list of course ids as a SQL construct, instead of loading the data - that is, turn it into a *derived table* by converting the query into a subquery (change the word .all() to .subquery()):

```
most_rated_course_id_subquery = session.query(
                    Review.course_id,
                ).\
                group_by(Review.course_id).\
                having(func.count(Review.course_id) > 1).\
                order_by(func.count(Review.course_id).desc()).\
                subquery()
```

one simple way to link that to Course is to use an IN:

```
 courses = session.query(Course).filter(
       Course.id.in_(most_rated_course_id_subquery)).all()
```

but that's essentially going to throw away the "ORDER BY" you're looking for and also doesn't give us any nice way of actually reporting on those counts along with the course results.   We need to have that count along with our Course so that we can report it and also order by it.   For this we use a JOIN from the "course" table to our derived table.  SQLAlchemy is smart enough to know to join on the "course_id" foreign key if we just call `join()`:

```
courses = session.query(Course).join(most_rated_course_id_subquery).all()
```

then to get at the count, we need to add that to the columns returned by our subquery along with a label so we can refer to it:

```
most_rated_course_id_subquery = session.query(
                        Review.course_id,
                        func.count(Review.course_id).label("count")
                    ).\
                    group_by(Review.course_id).\
                    having(func.count(Review.course_id) > 1).\
                    subquery()

courses = session.query(
                Course, most_rated_course_id_subquery.c.count
            ).join(
                most_rated_course_id_subquery
            ).order_by(
                most_rated_course_id_subquery.c.count.desc()
            ).all()
```

A great article I like to point out to people about GROUP BY and this kind of query is [SQL GROUP BY techniques](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2005/12/14/8546.aspx) which points out the common need for the "select from A join to (subquery of B with aggregate/GROUP BY)" pattern.